# Bootstrap menu is not showing in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar in Bootstrap that does not open in mobile view (there is the menu icon but when clicked no items are being shown)

My HTML code of the navbar is:

```
<header class="header_area">
    <div class="main-menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <div class="me-auto"></div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Protfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

I am new to bootstrap and would much appreciate your assistance on this one.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the full HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. So i think the problem is that you are not using the bootstrap CDNs properly.

Copy the below CDNs and paste them into your code.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

And if you are not using CDN and are using the downloaded files then please check your paths properly i.e, did you got the files correctly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly on my side. I think, the problem is you forget to attach the script for the javascript to work.

as stated in [Bootstrap Introduction Page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/), you need to enter this link tag for the CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and for the functionality to work, you require javascript. Try adding this to your project, before the closing body tag `</body>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine, check whether you have added these links:

**place this link in the head section:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**And place these links near the end of the body section:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```